# How can I convert a list of dictionaries to a dictionary with same keys and sum of the values?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example I have:

```
[{'Horror': 3, 'Romance': 3, 'Comedy': 1, 'Action': 3, 'History': 2}, {'Action': 0, 'Horror': 0, 'Romance': 0, 'Comedy': 0, 'History': 0, 'Adventure': 0}]
```

then I want:

```
{'Horror': 3, 'Romance': 3, 'Comedy': 1, 'Action': 3, 'History': 2, 'Adventure': 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `collections.defaultdict` will do it nicely

```
values = [{'Horror': 3, 'Romance': 3, 'Comedy': 1, 'Action': 3, 'History': 2},
          {'Horror': 1, 'Romance': 1, 'Comedy': 2, 'Action': 1, 'History': 0, 'Adventure': 0}]

result = defaultdict(int)
for subdict in values:
    for k, v in subdict.items():
        result[k] += v

# {'Horror': 4, 'Romance': 4, 'Comedy': 3, 'Action': 4, 'History': 2, 'Adventure': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a special kind of a `defaultdict(int)` so this can be done as:

```py
from collections import Counter

l = [{'Horror': 3, 'Romance': 3, 'Comedy': 1, 'Action': 3, 'History': 2},
     {'Action': 0, 'Horror': 0, 'Romance': 0, 'Comedy': 0, 'History': 0, 'Adventure': 0}]

c = Counter()
for d in l:
    c += d
print(c)
```

Will give:

```
Counter({'Horror': 3, 'Romance': 3, 'Action': 3, 'Comedy': 2, 'History': 2})
```

Note that `'Adventure'` is not there, but:

> Counter objects have a dictionary interface except that **they return
> a zero count for missing items** instead of raising a KeyError

So still:

```
>>> print(c['Adventure'])
0
```